# Django, Can not import urls from django.conf.urls

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on django restframework project. I build it and it was working well but then I tried makemigrations and I got following error. Please help me.

```
File "/code/eventful/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/code/eventful/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 446, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 632, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 625, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/code/eventful/eventful/urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    path('api/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_auth/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import url
ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py)
```

I tried makemigrations for my django project but I have got that error and I do not have any idea about this error. Can anybody help me. Please!

Comment: As of Django-4.0, url is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `url` was removed in Django 4.0
Look at the release notes here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/4.0/releases/4.0/#features-removed-in-4-0

`django.conf.urls.url() is removed`

Answer (score 1):

As of [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0), the `url` function is removed. Indeed, in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/) we see:

> `django.conf.urls.url()` is removed.

You thus are using `rest_auth` which is incompatible with the Django version. The [`django-rest-auth` project [GitHub]](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) still uses the `url(…)` function in the [**`urls.py`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/v0.9.3/rest_auth/urls.py).

You thus should downgrade Django (to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2)) to work with the `django-rest-auth`, or you should wait until the `django-rest-auth` makes a release that is compatible with [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0).